# Include the file size of the generated pdf

Tags: pdf, pdftex, filesystem-access

How can I include the (approximate) file size of the generated pdf within a `pdflatex` document? I envision having to compile it three times: once to create the pdf, a second time to write the size to an `.aux` file and the third pass will include it in the document. A minimal working example would be pedagogic and useful!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{\jobname.pdf}
  {\edef\Size{\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}}}
  {\def\Size{0}}

\begin{document}
\Size

xyz
\end{document}
```

You test the existence of the PDF file produced in the previous run *before* `pdftex` starts to write on a new one. The primitive `\pdffilesize` outputs the file size and with `\edef` you freeze this at the moment of executing `\pdffilesize`.

It won't be accurate to the byte, because of compression. I get

> 10401
>   9427
>   10258
>   10599
>   10466

in successive runs over the document. Dividing by 1024 and rounding could be better:

```
\IfFileExists{\jobname.pdf}
  {\edef\Size{\number\numexpr\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}/1024\relax\,KiB}}
  {\def\Size{0\,KiB}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an implementation in ConTeXt MkIV. I use `io.fileseize(...)` (part of ConTeXt's `l-io.lua` library) to find the size of the pdf file and add it to a two pass data list. By default, ConTeXt automatically recompiles the file if the two pass data list has changed, until a maximum of 8 runs after which it stops even if the two pass data is changing.

The filesize never stabilizes! Here is the implementation.

```
\def\OutputSize{0}
\def\PrevOutputSize{0}

\definetwopasslist{OutputSize}

% Read size from aux file
\gettwopassdata{OutputSize}
\iftwopassdatafound
    \xdef\PrevOutputSize{\twopassdata}
\fi

% Find the new size
\doiffile{\jobname.pdf}
    {\ctxlua{context.setvalue("OutputSize", io.size("\jobname.pdf"))}}
\savetwopassdata {OutputSize} {\PrevOutputSize} {\OutputSize}

% Useful for grepping the result
\writestatus{CHECK}{Outsize: \PrevOutputSize, Newsize: \OutputSize}

% Show figure size on footer
\setupfootertexts[\jobname: \OutputSize]

\starttext
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Starting in a scratch directory, compiling the file and grepping for `CHECK` in the output gives:

```
$ context test.tex | grep CHECK 
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 0
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 9380
CHECK           > Outsize: 9380, Newsize: 10033
CHECK           > Outsize: 10033, Newsize: 9751
CHECK           > Outsize: 9751, Newsize: 9858
CHECK           > Outsize: 9858, Newsize: 9921
CHECK           > Outsize: 9921, Newsize: 9706
CHECK           > Outsize: 9706, Newsize: 9952
```

As can be seen, even after 8 runs, the file size has not stabilized. I ran it again (without deleting any temporary file) and get

```
$ context test.tex | grep CHECK
CHECK           > Outsize: 9952, Newsize: 9892
CHECK           > Outsize: 9892, Newsize: 9856
CHECK           > Outsize: 9856, Newsize: 10083
CHECK           > Outsize: 10083, Newsize: 9899
CHECK           > Outsize: 9899, Newsize: 9732
CHECK           > Outsize: 9732, Newsize: 9965
CHECK           > Outsize: 9965, Newsize: 9927
CHECK           > Outsize: 9927, Newsize: 9793
```

So, even after 16 runs, the file size has not stabilized. I thought that the oscillation in file size is because the pdf output is compressed.

I added

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
```

on top of the file, and started from scratch again. This time I get

```
$ context test.tex | grep CHECK
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 0
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 15044
CHECK           > Outsize: 15044, Newsize: 15638
CHECK           > Outsize: 15638, Newsize: 15920
CHECK           > Outsize: 15920, Newsize: 15827
CHECK           > Outsize: 15827, Newsize: 15798
CHECK           > Outsize: 15798, Newsize: 15810
CHECK           > Outsize: 15810, Newsize: 15692

$ context test.tex | grep CHECK
CHECK           > Outsize: 15692, Newsize: 15865
CHECK           > Outsize: 15865, Newsize: 15730
CHECK           > Outsize: 15730, Newsize: 15827
CHECK           > Outsize: 15827, Newsize: 15798
CHECK           > Outsize: 15798, Newsize: 15810
CHECK           > Outsize: 15810, Newsize: 15692
CHECK           > Outsize: 15692, Newsize: 15865
CHECK           > Outsize: 15865, Newsize: 15730
```

Again, an oscillating file size and I don't know why that is happening.

So, in the end I decided to round the file size in kilo bytes, by diving the file size by `1024`.

```
% Find the new size
\doiffile{\jobname.pdf}
    {\ctxlua{context.setvalue("OutputSize", string.format("\%d", io.size("\jobname.pdf")/1024))}}
```

This time, as expected, the compilation stops after three runs.

```
$ context test.tex | grep CHECK  
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 0
CHECK           > Outsize: 0, Newsize: 9
CHECK           > Outsize: 9, Newsize: 9
```

Answer (score 3):

The file size does not stabilise because of how pdf compresses (the digits). As soon as you enter a new file size (with different digits), it compresses differently when converted to pdf.

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1234
\end{document}
```

and this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
4321
\end{document}
```

will produce files of equal size but this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1235
\end{document}
```

will produce a pdf file of a different size. So when you insert this new size into the document, just because the digits are different from the last time, it will produce a pdf file of a different size. However, you might find that after a number of iterations, the pdf file size appears to cycle through the same numbers.