# Inserting statistics of a resulting PDF file back into the document on the next run

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

This is an example of what I want to do:

1. After a run of `pdflatex`, calculate and store (into an auxiliary file?) the size of the resulting PDF file, as obtained from the Terminal command "`du -h file.pdf`", e.g. "50K". (This is just an example. It could be any other Terminal command not relating to the filesize.)
2. On the next run, typeset the stored text at a specific place on every page of the document, at a given inches to the top and right of the bottom-left point of the page.

How can this be done?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/include-the-file-size-of-the-generated-pdf)

Comment: @JuriRobl No, it isn't, because I'm not specifically asking for a size of a file (that was just an example that I, for better or worse, ended up choosing). It might as well be any other Terminal command, such as hash calculation, or a date, or whatever.

Comment: Sorry then. Can't you just store it as a `gdef` in the `aux` file? Or do you want a complete LaTeX solution?

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth Perhaps consider editing the title and lead-in hereto make it clear that this is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since pdfTeX 1.30.0 the expandable command `\pdffilesize` is available. Because the output file of the previous run will gets overwritten, the size should be asked as early as possible:

```
\edef\jobsize{\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  The file size is \jobsize~(\the\numexpr(\jobsize+512)/1024\relax~KB).
\end{document}
```

> [image: Example output]

However the printed file size will be part of the page. Thus the new output file will probably have a different file size. The file size depends on the included digits that are used in `\jobname`. If all digits are included anyway, then this does not matter. However
the page stream changes that is usually compressed. Therefore it is quite possible that the file size will never match the actual file size regardless the number of reruns.
Therefore rounding is a good idea.

Further remarks:

- LuaTeX can also be supported:

  ```
  \RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
  \makeatletter
  \edef\jobsize{\pdf@filesize{\jobname.pdf}}
  \makeatother
  ```
- If the file does not exist yet, then `\pdffilesize` or `\pdf@filesize` expands to the empty string, example:

  ```
  \ifx\jobsize\empty
    \textbf{??}%
  \else
    \jobsize
  \fi
  ```
- The size can also put in a reference to get warned by LaTeX because of changed references. But this might not be the best idea, because the size might never stabilize, see above.

**Update**

Some tricks allow the stabilizing of the file size:

- Include all digits (`\pdfincludechars`), even if some are not used. Then the font size remains the same.
- Use of a "form xobject" (a PDF terminus for reused material, similar to save boxes in (La)TeX. Then the page streams remain constant. Only the stream of the xobject varies.
  The randomized effect of compression can be eliminated by turning the compression off for this object.

It remains the xobject stream that varies with the file size. But the file size is stabilized so far that adding the file size in a reference in the `.aux` file can be tried to get rerun warnings.

The following example also uses `siunitx` for formatting the file size and puts
the file size at a fixed location in the page as requested in the question.
Package `atbegshi` is used for that purpose.

```
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}% support LuaTeX
\makeatletter
\edef\jobsize{\pdf@filesize{\jobname.pdf}}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareBinaryPrefix{\kibi}{Ki}{10}
\DeclareBinaryPrefix{\mebi}{Mi}{20}
\DeclareBinaryPrefix{\gibi}{Gi}{30}
\DeclareSIUnit\byte{B}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\printjobsize}{%
  \@ifundefined{xform@jobsize}{%
    \begingroup
      \sbox0{%
        \sisetup{detect-mode=false,mode=text}%
        \pdfincludechars\font{0123456789 ()}%
        \pdfincludechars\font{\si{\kibi\byte}\si{\mebi\byte}\si{\gibi\byte}}%
        \ifx\jobsize\@empty
          \textbf{??}%
        \else
          \expandafter\num\expandafter{\jobsize}~bytes (%
          \ifnum\numexpr(\jobsize+512)/1024\relax<10 %
          \else
            \ifnum\numexpr(\jobsize+524288)/1048576\relax<10 %
              \expandafter\SI\expandafter{\the\numexpr(\jobsize+512)/1024\relax
            \else
              \ifnum\numexpr(\jobsize+536870912)/1073741824\relax<10 %
                \expandafter\SI\expandafter{\the\numexpr(\jobsize+524288)/10485
              \else
                \expandafter\SI\expandafter{\the\numexpr(\jobsize+536870912)/10
              \fi
            \fi
            )%
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
      \pdfcompresslevel=0\relax
      \immediate\pdfxform0\relax
      \xdef\xform@jobsize{\the\pdflastxform}%
    \endgroup
  }{}%
  \pdfrefxform\xform@jobsize\relax
}
% Adding the file size as reference of the new reference class "jobsize"
% in the ".aux" file.
\newcommand*{\newjobsize}{\@newl@bel{jobsize}{jobsize}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\providecommand\string\newjobsize[1]{}}%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\newjobsize{\jobsize}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Put the file size 10mm from the left margin and 10mm from the bottom
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{picture}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(10mm,\dimexpr-\paperheight+10mm\relax){% 
      \makebox(0,0)[lb]{File size: \printjobsize}%
    }%
  }%  
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}  
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Hello World}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

> [image: First page with file size]

Comment: Do you know how the text could be horizontally centered at the bottom of the page instead? (With the vertical distance from the bottom remaining the same.)

Comment: `\put(.5\paperwidth,...){\makebox(0,0)[b]{...}}` should do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can take the approach of the [`vc` bundle](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/support/vc/) to do this sort of thing. The basic idea is to use `\write18` to call a shell script which writes the relevant macro definitions to a file which can then be used. Here's an example for getting the word count in your document.

First your tex document should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\immediate\write18{./wc foo.tex}
\input{wc}
\begin{document}
Foo and things

Words in text: \texcount

\end{document}
```

And your `wc` file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is the 'wc' file inspired by 'vc' available on CTAN

texcount $1 | awk '/Words in text/ {print "\\gdef\\texcount{" $4 "}"}' > wc.tex
```

For this to work you'll need to add `./wc` to your `shell_escape_commands` list in your `texmf.cnf` and make the file executable.

Now, every time you run latex on the file, it will call `./wc` on the file `foo.tex` which will word count the file and extract the relevant information from it and make it accessible with the `\texcount` macro which is in the inputted `wc.tex` file. You can then use `fanchdr` or some other such package to put the info where you like.

---

I'm pretty sure this isn't the simplest or most robust way to get the right info out of `textcount`, but this is the method that the original `vc` bundle uses for getting stuff out of `git` and I was slavishly copying that…