# After a series of nested \includegraphics, some PDF viewers fail to display the image

Tags: graphics, pdf, ps2pdf

I'll admit this is a convoluted example, but I like drawing with TikZ and LaTeX and this particular issue has come up for me more than once.

The minimal working example takes a few files, but in a nutshell - a PDF is produced at each compile with the [current filesize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/include-the-file-size-of-the-generated-pdf) in it. After a set number of includes some viewers (`evince`,`okular`,`acroread*`) fail to display the deeply nested images, while others segfault (`xpdf`)  and only one (`gs`) shows the full image correctly.

*Note that `acroread` won't fail on the example below, but will if you keep cranking up the iterations.

## first.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}\begin{document}start\end{document}
```

## next.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\IfFileExists{\jobname.pdf}
  {\edef\Size{\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}}}
  {\def\Size{0}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength\fboxsep{1pt}
\newcommand{\X}{\includegraphics{first.pdf}}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
\framebox{\Size} \\ \X
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

## Makefile

```
all:
    make first
    make block
    make block
    make block

    evince next.pdf
    gs next.pdf

first:
    pdflatex first.tex

next:
    pdflatex next.tex
    cp next.pdf first.pdf

block:
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
    make next
```

## Examples (`gs` vs `evince`)

[image]
[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why can't the viewers display the deeply nested images?
2. By running `pdf2ps -> ps2pdf` the problem is fixed, but is there any
   risk for more complicated images being mangled (i.e. using TikZ or fonts
   with ConTeX)?

Comment: Can you try also with `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}` in `first.tex`?

Comment: What is `make first` supposed to do? How do you run that Makefile? With `make all` I get `missing separator`.

Comment: I still get `Missing separator`.

Comment: @egreg You have to replace the spaces at the begin of the indented lines by a tabulator.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks, I didn't realize that the markup ate the tab characters and replaced them with spaces. Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: @percusse No change on adding `[preview]`. Using "first.tex" is not necessary, and any starting pdf should have the same effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

evince, okular and xpdf share a common heritage for their pdf parsing facilities (evince is based on poppler which is based on xpdf; okular is based on kpdf is based on xpdf) and they all explicitly limit the form recursion depth precisely to avoid infinite recursion on damaged pdfs that have forms who include themselves (possibly via a convoluted route). This could also be a DoS attack from maliciously-constructed pdfs. [Here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/commit/poppler/Gfx.cc?id=760e814a6d26db8eba567520aad771002e11357a&context=6) is a very recent patch to poppler to increase the recursion depth from 20 to 100, but presumably your installation of evince uses the older limit of 20.

The PDF specification PDF 32000-1:2008 doesn't seem to explicitly limit the allowed recursion level for form XObjects but it does say in section 8.10.1 that

> When the `Do` operator is applied to a form XObject, a conforming reader
>   shall perform the following tasks:
>   a) Saves the current graphics state,
>   as if by invoking the `q` operator (see 8.4.4, "Graphics State
>   Operators")
>   [....]
>   e) Restores the saved
>   graphics state, as if by invoking the `Q` operator (see 8.4.4, "Graphics
>   State Operators")

and in Appendix C.2, table C.1 it gives a limit on `q`/`Q` nesting as 28 levels deep, based on the fact that these operators map to PostScript `gsave` and `grestore` operators when converting PDF to PostScript (table B.1 of the PostScript spec, 3rd edition gives a maximum  `gsave` level of 31, and presumably a couple of these are needed for other purposes, leaving 28 for PDF `q`/`Q` and form XObjects).

Comment: Any idea on why runnning `pdf2ps -> ps2pdf` fixes the problem? Do the images get somehow "mapped down"?

Comment: Yes, it seems ghostscript flattens the forms. Actually `ps2pdf next.pdf next-refried.pdf` is enough, despite the name of the command it can take pdf as input.