# Wrong file size of PDF

Tags: file-size

My code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.pdf}
{\edef\Size{\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}}}
{\def\Size{0}} The file size is \Size~Byte\\

\edef\jobsize{\pdffilesize{\jobname.pdf}}
The file size is \jobsize~(\the\numexpr(\jobsize+512)/1024\relax~kB)\\

\end{document}
```

Mouse Right Click File Size >>> **14,3 kB (14.342 bytes)**

Generated Log File Written  >>> **Output written on 2.pdf (1 page, 14342 bytes).**

PDF file Written            >>> **The file size is 14433 (15 kB)**

My 6 try picture

[image]

Very interesting result.

Why is not the same? I didn't find duplicate another question. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Related to: [Include the file size of the generated pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/include-the-file-size-of-the-generated-pdf)

Comment: I ran your code on my system. The file size printed on the pdf file changes when I do it again and again... what's the reason?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: Because the current file size is used to calculate something, the result is shipped out and this changes again the file size, it's a *vicious circle*, but after some runs, it should stabilize, since the number of digits remains fixed then.

Comment: @Özgür: After three or four runs (without changing the document additionally), all three numbers are equal.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer so long as the time doesn't change sufficiently that compression is altered by a byte or two

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know that there is compression involved, but I noticed, that the numbers differ only in three runs in the range of about 30 byte, afterwards they are stable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes but if the time changes such that you get a list of repeated digits or anything else that affects the compression algorithm I think it's possible the date string in the file could be compressed by a different amount (perhaps, I don't know what pdftex actually does here)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The file size does not converge. I have the following sizes, 13833, 13608, 14006, 13537, 13801, 13789, 13983 printed on the PDF file.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: It ended up with 13616 byte, after multiple compilation and waiting for some minutes in order to check whether the time information affects this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am getting the same repeated file sizes...

Comment: If you have not used all numbers, it is possible that the included font subset is different each time. Have you tried using all the digits in your document?

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Add my 6 try picture edited in my question.