# LuaLaTeX: How to include a generated file size in document?

Tags: luatex, filesystem-access

How to include a generated file size in document with LuaLaTeX? Similar question was answered, but for pdflatex case [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/include-the-file-size-of-the-generated-pdf). The solution does not work with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pdftexcmds` package then a Lua implementation of the pdftex `\pdffilesize` command is available  as `\pdf@filesize`

Comment: on windows it doesn't work (with pdflatex neither), the pdf seems to be open already. (But if it worked one could also try the modern `\file_size:n`).